# where do I put an API curl request in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I'm using the G Adventure API to populate a database in my super-basic rails app.
The docs https://developers.gadventures.com/docs/index.html#api-endpoint 
say to use a CURL request to get back JSON data, which obviously works fine, but what I'm wondering is where I should then store this request in the app itself...
Hunch is that it should be linked to a method inside the controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really want to use curl in the application. Instead it would be better to use Ruby's Net::HTTP to make the request. Also, if relates to the logic of your app, and if you are saving the data in a database, it sounds like it does, this sort of thing belongs on the model, not the controller.

So in your model try

Net::HTTP::Get.new(API END POINT URL)